# Calling setter and getter from a class that extends in the main class

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, getter-setter

How can i call the setter and getter of a class that's extends the main class.
I have my Main Class, BankAccount, and i have CheckingAccount that extends BankAccount

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount  {
private double overdraftProtection;


public CheckingAccount(){

};

public CheckingAccount(String accountNo, String accountName, 
        double initBalance) {
    super(accountNo, accountName, initBalance);
}

public CheckingAccount(String accountNo, String accountName) {
    super(accountNo, accountName);
}

public double getOverdraftProtection() {
    return overdraftProtection;
}

public void setOverdraftProtection(double overdraftProtection) {
    this.overdraftProtection = overdraftProtection;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
    // TODO: code for withdrawal
}
```

In my GUI, i want to call the setter and getter of the checking account. I have tried `account.setOverdraftProtection` but there is no available for that.

My GUI:

```
private void btnSaveAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

if(rad_savings.isSelected()){

            account.setAccountType("Savings");
            account.setInterest(Double.parseDouble(txt_interestrate.getText()));

    }
    else{

        account = new CheckingAccount();
        account.setAccountType("Checking");


        }
```

Comment: is `setOverdraftProtection()` a method every implementation of `BankAccount` should have?

Comment: No, theres a radiobutton for accounttype, if checking account is selected, that's only time it will implement.

Comment: Why so you call `BankAccount` your main class?

Comment: @Eric Jablow -- Sorry mate, could you please explain further your comment?

Comment: What did you mean by a main class?  Do you mean the class that has the `main` method?  Just curious.  By the way, do you really need a setAccountType method?  The way you have it, someone can create a `CheckingAccount` and call `setAccountType("Savings") on it.  Better to make that read-only and just have a getter.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, i mean BankAccount is my main, all my other classes just extending it. I have this, Create account GUI, user will input accountno,accountname, select his account type if savings, if savings, interesrate field will be available, if checking, overdraftprotection will be available. All inputs from user will be via textfields

Comment: Ah.  That's reasonable.  So, call this `NewAccountPanel`.  Have the top part of the panel be for the items in `BankAccount` and for the radio buttons that distinguish between checking, savings, money-market, and so on.  Have the bottom part be for the items needed for the particular type of account, and swap them in and out as the user switches account type.

Answer (score 0):

The base class `BankAccount` is required to implement `setOverdraftProtection` to that it can be available to all implementations without downcasting, for instance

```
BankAccount account = new CheckingAccount();
account.setOverdraftProtection(2000);
```

`setOverdraftProtection` can be declared as `abstract` to avoid giving the base class any implementation.

```
public class BankAccount  {
  public abstract void setOverdraftProtection(double overdraftProtection);
  ...
}
```

Aside: In reality you would never use `double` to represent a monetary amount - `BigDecimal` would be used instead.

Comment: But i have this:
    `private voib tnSaveAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();
       account.setAccountName(txt_accountname.getText());
            account.setAccountNo(txt_accountnumber.getText());
           account.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(txt_initialbalance.getText()));`
When trying to use `BankAccount account = new CheckingAccount();
account.setOverdraftProtection(txt_overdraft.getText());` it gives me an error

Comment: The compiler does not realize that `account` must be a `CheckingAccount` at that last line.  All it knows is that `account` is a `BankAccount`.  And `BankAccount` does not have `setOverdraftProtection`, so the compiler reports an error.  Use two different panels; one for `BankAccount` and one for `CheckingAccount`.

Comment: @dyonas Declare _all_ the intended methods in `BankAccount` making specific `methods` such as `setOverdraftProtection` `abstract`

Comment: Any class that has an abstract method must itself be abstract.  The original poster used `new BankAccount()` in his example, so `BankAccount` cannot have abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

The object type created is the BankAccount so its not aware of CheckingAccount methods . override the method by declaring in BankAccount 
Or simple option to be

`if(account instanceof Checkingaccount)`

`account.setOverdraftProtection(2000);`

Comment: You still need to cast `account` here.

Comment: after `account=new CheckingAccount()` is called

Comment: That doesn't matter.  `account` is declared as a `BankAccount`. so you can only call `BankAccount` methods on it.

Comment: with this check you can call `CheckingAccount` methods on it as it is confirmed that it is an instance of `CheckingAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

Since only `CheckingAccounts` can have overdraft protection, you need a `BankAccountPanel` that has widgets only for the items in `BankAccount`, and you need a `CheckingAccountPanel` that can extend it that has widgets for the `CheckingAccount` items too.

So, here are the two account classes I suggest.  A real system would have a database, of course.

```
public abstract class BankAccount {
    private final String id;
    private final Owner owner;
    private BigDecimal balance;

    // constructors, getters, toString elided.  No setters.

    public final void deposit(BigDecimal amount) throws BankException {        
        mayDeposit(amount); //Throw if amount <= 0.  Elided.
        balance = balance.add(amount);
    }

    public final void withdraw(BigDecimal amount) throws BankException {
        mayWithdraw(amount);
        balance = balance.subtract(amount);
    }

    /**
     * Throw an exception if the owner tries to withdraw more money than he has.
     * @throws BankException If withdrawl < 0 or withdrawl >= balance.
     */
    protected void mayWithdraw(BigDecimal withdrawal) throws BankException {
        if (withdrawal.signum() != 1) {
            throw new BankException();
        }
        if (balance.compareTo(withdrawal) < 0) {
            throw new BankException();
        }
    }
}

public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
    private BigDecimal overdraftLimit;
    private BankAccount overdraftAccount;
    // constructors, etc.
    // getters and setters for overdraft variables.
    protected void mayWithdraw(BigDecimal withdrawal) throws BankException {
        if (withdrawal.signum() != 1) {
            throw new BankException();
        }
        if (balance.add(overdraftLimit).compareTo(withdrawal) < 0) {
            throw new BankException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it's been a while since I did Swing, and I'm not going to take an hour to fill out a full example.  I suggest you create a `JPanel` and give it a `BorderLayout`.

In the `NORTH` part of it, I would put the owner's information and then a set of radio buttons for the type of account. In the `CENTER` part of it, I would put a dedicated CheckingAccountPanel, or SavingsAccountPanel, or whatever type of panel you need for your account type.  If the user chooses a new radio button, you would swap the account panel here for the newly-needed one. You would use events for this.  Tn the `SOUTH` part of the main panel, I'd put the `Create` and `Cancel` buttons.

Each XXXAccountPanel would be tied to an XXXAccount and would fill it in as the user entered values.  So, you can have an BankAccountPanel with the id, owner, and balance, and you could extend it or use it in a SavingsAccountPanel that would have the interestRate too. But the SavingsAccountPanel would work with a SavingsAccount, and so would not set overdraft protection on it.  The CheckingAccountPanel would not set interest rates.

### Comments

I didn't create these classes on my home system, but look at the similar code below and the compilation results. The variable `n` can only ever be a `BigDecimal`, but you can't call specific `BigDecimal` methods on it.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class NumberTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number n = new BigDecimal("42");
        System.out.println(n.toEngineeringString());
    }
}
```

From `javac`:

```
NumberTest.java:6: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : method toEngineeringString()  
location: class java.lang.Number  
        System.out.println(n.toEngineeringString());  
                            ^  
1 error
```

Comment: Sorry for long trails, but could you please provide me an example so that i can get it, step by step.